# Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-credentials

Trying to use S3 client in my ECS app for uploading files into S3 bucket (let's call it `bucket1`),
S3 client is instantiated as follows:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
 
private S3Client getClient(){


    return S3Client.builder().build();
}
```

Task definition has been configured to use `ecsTaskExecutionRole` as "Task execution role", so I have added the following permissions policy to it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The same permissions policy has been added to `ecsInstanceRole` as well.

When I try to upload something, the following exception is dropped:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), ProfileCredentialsProvider(), ContainerCredentialsProvider(), InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()]) : [SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(): Either the environment variable AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE or the javaproperty aws.webIdentityTokenFile must be set., ProfileCredentialsProvider(): Profile file contained no credentials for profile 'default': ProfileFile(profiles=[]), ContainerCredentialsProvider(): Cannot fetch credentials from container - neither AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI or AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment variables are set., InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(): Failed to load credentials from IMDS.]
```

Kind of lost here - am I supposed to specify AWS credentials in the list of environment variables? How to pass credentials otherwise?

By the way, "Task role" has been set to "None", in task definition, if that matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your task definition, you should set the **task role parameter to the IAM role** that you created earlier. This task role is used by the container to access AWS services.

Alternatively, you can use environment variables to create clients as well by setting variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: yep, that was it, I had suspicions that the reason is empty task role, but thanks for pointing out the right direction. interesting that putting s3 permissions into `ecsInstanceRole` has no effect, looks like it is used only for accessing ECR and Cloudwatch logs

Comment: although when I previously added permissions for s3, glue and athena actions for one of my AWS Batch job definitions, into `ecsInstanceRole`, it worked. looks like for ECS, it is supposed to have only ECR and CW policies, while for AWS Batch, it could have any policy. or probably AWS Batch uses `ecsInstanceRole` as task role by default, while for ECS is it initally empty